# Check uniformly distributed continuous random variable

Tags: probability, distributions

I have a random variable which I know is uniformly distributed, and I **expect** it to be distributed between the range $[0,1]$. Then, I generate (simulate) 100 realizations of the variable.

**The question**: Which is the best way to find the probability that the underlying "actual" range of the variable is in fact $[0,1]$ from the realizations?

Its clear that if the 100 realizations are within the range $[0.51, 0.69]$, the probability is very low, while if they are within the range $[0.01, 0.99]$, it should be high.

I tried simply to compute the actual vs expected range ratio 
$$
((0.69-0.51)/(1-0)) = 0.08, 
$$
and assumed that it was the probability $p$ of each realization. Then computed the probability of it happening 100 times as $p^{100}$.

The problem is that, for a correct case, in which the original range was in fact $[0,1]$, the realization range turned out to be $[0.02,0.93]$ and the computed probability is very low $0.91^{100} = 0.0012$, which does not makes sense.

So, what is it that I am getting completely wrong?

**EDIT. Clarifications thanks to @whuber**
(1) I am attempting to check that the range of the underlying variable is in fact [0,1] (for validation purposes) (2) I just want to check the range and know how likely is that it is in fact [0,1]. (3) realizations are independent $rand(1,100)$ in Matlab

Comment: Not much.  You are testing $H_0: X \sim u(0,1) $  vs  $H_a: X \sim U(a,b)$ with $0 \le a,b \le 1$ and not equality in both cases.  You propose the perfectly reasonable test statistic Z = Max - min, where you reject if $Z < \lambda$ and determine $\lambda$ by $P_0(Z < \lambda) = .05$, say .  This calc. is a little off as you ignore the min, also it's odd you get exactly 0 as the min, which shouldn't happen, but I doubt the slight differences make much difference.

Comment: The zero is an error but it makes the probability slightly larger.... So, from your answer I get that I am getting the right answer, so it must mean I am asking the wrong question...

Comment: What do you mean by 'random process' here? Are the realizations actually single random numbers (drawn independently) or is there some time series?

Comment: I mean $rand(1,100)$ in Matlab... =), so I think single random numbers?...

Comment: (1) Are you attempting to *estimate* the range of the underlying process?  (2) If you want to develop a probability distribution for that range, then you need to stipulate a prior probability for the range.  Do you have one in mind? (3) Are the successive observations of your process independent or not? (4) What would be the difference between generating "100 realizations of the process" and generating one realization that is 100 times longer?

Comment: @whuber (1) I am attempting to check that the range of the underlying process is in fact [0,1] (for validation purposes) (2) I just want to check the range and know how likely is that it is in fact [0,1]. (3) realizations are independent $rand(1,100)$ in Matlab. (4) none, probably I am misusing the concept "random process"

Comment: That comment substantially clarifies your question.  Would you mind editing your original post to incorporate those refinements?

Comment: The expected range is not one for a finite sample from a uniform distribution so your ratio formula is off. This looks like what might be called a two-sided German tank problem to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it is meaningless to find a probability (unless you first specify a prior distribution of the endpoints), you can find the *relative likelihood.*  A good basis for comparison would be the alternative hypothesis that the numbers are drawn from a uniform distribution between a lower bound $L$ and upper bound $U$.

[Sufficient statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) are the minimum $X$ and maximum $Y$ of *all* the data (assuming each number is obtained independently).  It doesn't matter whether you draw the data in batches or not.  When drawn from the interval $[0,1]$, the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$ is continuous and has density

$$\eqalign{f(x,y) &= \binom{n}{1,n-2,1}(y-x)^{n-2}\mathcal{I}(0\le x\le y\le 1) \\ &= n(n-1)(y-x)^{n-2}\mathcal{I}(0\le x\le y\le 1).}$$

When scaled by $U-L$ and shifted by $L$, this density becomes

$$f_{(L,U)}(x,y) = (U-L)^{-n} n(n-1)(y-x)^{n-2}\mathcal{I}(L\le x\le y\le U).$$

Obviously this is greatest when $L = x$ and $U=y$.

The [relative likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Relative_likelihood) is their ratio, best expressed as a logarithm:

$$\Lambda(X,Y) = \log\left(\frac{f_{(X,Y)}(X,Y)}{f(X,Y)}\right) = -n\log(Y-X).$$

A small value of this is evidence for the hypothesis $(L,U)=(0,1)$; larger values are evidence against it.  Of course if $X \lt 0$ or $Y \gt 1$ the hypothesis is controverted.  But when the hypothesis is true, for large $n$ (greater than $20$ or so), $2\Lambda(X,Y)$ will have approximately a $\chi^2(4)$ distribution. Assuming $X \ge 0$ and $Y \le 1$, this enables you to reject the hypothesis when the chance of a $\chi^2(4)$ variable *exceeding* $2\Lambda(X,Y)$ becomes so small you can no longer suppose the large value can be attributed to chance alone.

I will not attempt to prove that the $\chi^2(4)$ distribution is the one to use; I will merely show that it works by simulating a large number of independent values of $2\Lambda(X,Y)$ when the hypothesis is true.  Since you have the ability to generate large values of $n$, let's take $n=500$ as an example.

[image: Figure]

*$100,000$ results are shown for $n=500$.  The red curve graphs the density of a $\chi^2(4)$ variable.  It closely agrees with the histogram.*

---

As a worked example consider the situation posed in the question where $n=100$, $X= 0.51$, and $Y=0.69$.  Now

$$-2\Lambda(0.51, 0.69) = -2(100\log(0.69 - 0.51)) = 343.$$

The corresponding $\chi^2(4)$ probability is less than $10^{-72}$: although we would never trust the accuracy of the $\chi^2$ approximation this far out into the tail (even with $n=100$ observations), this value is so small that certainly these data were not obtained from $100$ independent uniform$(0,1)$ variables!

In the second situation where $X=0.01$ and $Y=0.99$,

$$-2\Lambda(0.01, 0.99) = -2(100\log(0.99 - 0.01)) = 4.04.$$

Now the $\chi^2(4)$ probability is $0.40 = 40\%$, quite consistent with the hypothesis that $(L,U)=(0,1)$.

---

BTW, here's `R` code to perform simulations.  I have reset it to just $10,000$ iterations so that it will take less than one second to complete.

```R
n <- 500 # Sample size
N <- 1e4 # Number of simulation trials
lambda <- apply(matrix(runif(n*N), nrow=n), 2, function(x) -2 * n * log(diff(range(x))))
#
# Plot the results.
#
hist(lambda, freq=FALSE, breaks=seq(0, ceiling(max(lambda)), 1/4), border="#00000040", 
     main="Histogram", xlab="2*Lambda")
curve(dchisq(x, 4), add=TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you need, but let's first take a look at how to estimate the lower and upper boundaries. It is claimed on Wikipedia that the uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimators for the continuous uniform distribution on $(a,b)$ are the maximum spacing estimators $$ \hat{a}={{nx_{(1)}-x_{(n)}} \over {n-1}},\ \ \hat{b}={{nx_{(n)}-x_{(1)}} \over {n-1}}, $$ where $x_{(1)}$ is the minimum observed value, $x_{(n)}$ is the maximum observed value, and $n$ is the sample size. Note that $\hat{a}$ can be negative and $\hat{b}$ can be greater than one when the population is $U(0,1)$.

I don't know if this is enough for you or not. It seems you really want to test whether your output is truly $U(0,1).$ If that is the case, why not just conduct a K-S test since your desired distribution is fully specified? In this case, if the null hypothesis is true, your p-values should also have a $U(0,1)$ distribution.

Comment: What I need is a test on the data that passes when the underlying distribution is in fact $U(0,1)$ and fails when is not (for example if it is $U(0,0.5)$. That's all. Thanks for the suggestion, I don't know what a K-S test is.

Comment: Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness-of-fit test.